# Why does the derivative become $x=r\dot\theta\cos(\theta)$ when calculating angular velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, differentiation, angular-velocity

This is **not** a homework question because I do not want help with solving my homework. I would rather want an explanation of why the derivative of this seems to break math as I know it.

***Background information:***

The problem from book:
[image]

Part of the solution from Slader:
[image]

***My question:***

When taking derivative of $x=r\sin(\theta)$, shouldn't this become $x=r\cos(\theta)$?

Apparently it does not, it should be $x=r\dot\theta\cos(\theta)$. Why is that? I cannot understand where $\dot \theta$ comes from

Comment: You left out the overdot on $x$ in your last two equations.

Comment: $\dot x=r\cos\theta$ can’t possibly be correct because the two sides are dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: You ae taking divative with respect to time and $\theta$ is a function of time. From that the $\dot\theta$ factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since theta is also a function of time, you need to apply the chain rule. Angle is variable due to the horizontal motion of arm OP. Regardless, the very fact that they are asking for the first and second derivatives of angle implies that is non-constant in nature, else they would be zero.

Comment: Isn't $\theta$ just an angle?

Comment: Does $\theta$ change value in time? If so, it is a function of time.

Comment: @J.Doe If $x$ changes, from the drawing $\theta$ also changes. From $x = r \sin \theta$ you get $dx/d\theta = r \cos \theta$, but $\dot x$ means $dx/dt$, not $dx/d\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

The angle subtended $\theta$ is varying with the x. So whenever x changes theta will change. Since x is a function of time, it depends on time. But theta depends on x, and it is clear from that theta depends on time. In $x=sin (\theta)$ ,$ \theta$ is the variable and while we taking the derivative with respect to time, $\theta$ should be considered. If $\theta$ was not changing, the function would be constant and you cannot take cos when differentiating